# Map and Reduce a JSON Object with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, angular, rxjs

Consider this object below:

```
    {
    "_items": [
        {
            "_id": "player_1",
            "score": {
                "a": -4.74,
                "b": 0.71,
                "c": -4.04,
                "d": 3.37,
                "e": 0.22,
                "f": 1.09,
                "g": -2.17              
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would to Map and Reduce and generate a new object containing only the score object :

```
{
    "a": -4.74,
    "b": 0.71,
    "c": -4.04,
    "d": 3.37,
    "e": 0.22,
    "f": 1.09,
    "g": -2.17
}
```

I was thinking something like this might be moving in the right directions, but does not seem to do what I was expecting:

```
this.service.getscore()
  .map(res => res.json())
  .map(v => v._items[0].score)
  .subscribe(data => { this.sc = data });
```

`console.log(this.sc);` will give me the same result as the first json.

While I recognize that it is probably better and easier to do this on the server-side, it's not possible in my case. I am wondering if what I am trying to do can be done on the client side with JavaScript. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just `return json['_items'][0].score`?

Comment: thanks for the answer but I'm not sure what do you mean by json[..]

Comment: *"console.log(this.sc); will give me the same result as the first json."* And what are you expecting??

Comment: this.service.getscore().map(res => res.json()).map(v => v._items[0].score).subscribe(data => { this.sc= data }); should give me the second result

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with "map/reduce"? Also, if `_items` contains more than one child, what do you want to return? The first one only?

Comment: the server side's json structure is bad. _items contains only one child. I want to return the score object only.

Comment: You do know that `this.sc` will not be set until the subscription handler runs, and until then will have some previous value, right?

Comment: no I don't. that's why I'm asking for help. I'm new to observables and rxjs

Comment: How can I change it to get the current value? thx

Answer (score 1):

Could you try my code below:

```
var item = {
  "_items": [{
      "_id": "player_1",
      "score": {
        "a": -4.74,
        "b": 0.71,
        "c": -4.04,
        "d": 3.37,
        "e": 0.22,
        "f": 1.09,
        "g": -2.17
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "player_2",
      "score": {
        "a": -4.74,
        "b": 0.71,
        "c": -4.04,
        "d": 3.37,
        "e": 0.22,
        "f": 1.09,
        "g": -2.17
      }
    }
  ]
};
let arrayScores = item._items.map(el => el.score);
console.log(arrayScores);
```

There is the arrayScores value:

```
[{
  a: -4.74,
  b: 0.71,
  c: -4.04,
  d: 3.37,
  e: 0.22,
  f: 1.09,
  g: -2.17
}, {
  a: -4.74,
  b: 0.71,
  c: -4.04,
  d: 3.37,
  e: 0.22,
  f: 1.09,
  g: -2.17
}]
```

Does it make sense ?

Comment: i'm getting the json through a http request and then assigning an empty object to that json . I don't have any ._items defined.

Comment: You mean that you received the result in string from HTTP response ?.
Have you tried to convert it to JSON object by using `JSON.parse(result_string)`

Comment: no it's not a string. I'm using observables and mapping it into json : can striguify it but cannot parse it beacuse it's a json already : this.service.getscore()
  .map(res => res.json())
  .map(v => v._items[0].score)
  .subscribe(data => { this.sc = data });

Answer (score 0):

the simplier, the better ?:

```
    var json = [{
        "_items": [
            {
                "_id": "player_1",
                "score": {
                    "a": -4.74,
                    "b": 0.71,
                    "c": -4.04,
                    "d": 3.37,
                    "e": 0.22,
                    "f": 1.09,
                    "g": -2.17
                }
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "_items": [
            {
                "_id": "player_2",
                "score": {
                    "a": -4.74,
                    "b": 0.71,
                    "c": -4.04,
                    "d": 3.37,
                    "e": 0.22,
                    "f": 1.09,
                    "g": -2.17
                }
            }
        ]
    }];
var scores = [];
for (var i = 0, var j = json.length; i <= j; i++) {
    scores.push(json[i]._items[0].score);
}
```

Comment: json is an object that contains an array . it would have been easier if it was an array. also, I'm getting property .length does not exist on type {}.

Comment: I am getting the json from a web server with an angular service and then assigning an empty object sc={} to that json. I can't use dots to access it

Answer (score 0):

As Maria Ines Parnisari mentioned, you can extract exactly the data you want, by stepping into the JSON you are receiving. So we just extract the content of `score` and assign it to an object:

**Service:**

```ts
getscore() {
  return this.http.get('src/data.json')
    .map(res => res.json()._items[0].score) // let's get the content of 'score'
}
```

Component:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getscore()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.sc = data;
    })
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/oewvPDr33JfYcvYpAs2f?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

[**Working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/xjj0s1cf/)

```js
this.sc = {
    "_items": [
        {
            "_id": "player_1",
            "score": {
                "a": -4.74,
                "b": 0.71,
                "c": -4.04,
                "d": 3.37,
                "e": 0.22,
                "f": 1.09,
                "g": -2.17              
            }
        }
    ]
};

console.log(this.sc._items[0].score);
```